# How to recognise electro magnetic mode in patch antenna based on current voltage profile

Tags: antenna

In my microstrip antenna of L=lambda/2 shown bellow we have current and voltage profiles based on the fact the edged are open circuit.
What electro magnetic mod is that?
How do i recognise what kind of TM mode is it based on the current voltage profile?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The H field current is strongest just under and around the feed and the asymmetric geometry of the feed point and ground plane rectangular shape affect the H field on A/m and consequent return loss vs Theta.

[image]

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijap/2017/5924157/fig3/
With free space impedance and ground plane impedance to patch with some gap, the edges aren't exactly open circuit, yet a partial strip ground patch is adequate to conduct the current for the patch to radiate an EH field.

Comment: Hello Tonny, Actually i ment to ask about the inset feed microstrip patch antenna as shown in the link bellow.
How can i see TM01 properties in the antenna shown in the link?
sorry for misunderstanding.

https://ibb.co/Ch3cNkh

Comment: Run it thru simulation

Comment: Hello Tony ,i know that the answer is TM01,this is the dominant mode for the patch antenna ,but  dont know how to prove it.
could you help me with understanding What kind of boudary conditions to use and in waht equations to put them?
Thanks.